# Is it safe to use basic authentication with localhost service via PHP Curl without SSL?

Tags: php, security, rest, curl, basic-authentication

I have a local service accessible via an HTTP REST API that requires basic authentication.  Is it generally secure to call it using this with PHP Curl?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:XXXX/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
```

My guess is yes since it's all local, but I thought I'd toss it out for confirmation.

Comment: Safe against what / who?

Comment: Should have said "secure" rather than "safe."  I updated the question and added some PHP.

Comment: why would you make a curl request to  localhost from localhost rather inefficient.

Comment: @Dagon - The service is only accessible via HTTP REST.  It's a binary running on Apache.

Comment: @Inator: Secure against what / who?

Answer (score 0):

SSL provides 2 forms of protection (which complement and complete each other):

1. It prevents 3rd parties from being able to read your traffic in transit
2. It allows you to confirm that you're connected to who you think you're connected to.

If you don't have any concern with either of those forms of attack, then you don't need to use SSL encryption.  I'm betting on a local connection, unless your local network is a government institution or Fortune 100 company, there's not much concern of your being compromised, leastways not by anything intelligent enough to do anything other than pop up ads in your browser or send out spam.  If you're really unlucky, maybe a keylogger, but none of these things would sniff HTTP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

For REST security please check OAuth 2.0, but if you do not want to use complicated authentication mechanism you can just use HTTPS as you are informing it is local, but do not use basic auth over http.

Comment: There aren't very many risks to non-HTTPS over loopback that do not imply bigger issues.